# REGEX for spaces between alpha numeric string

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you help me build a regex which will match any one of below patterns:

1. `N0007120DJKAWE` (9 to 14 char of alphanumeric)
2. `N  0007120DJKAWE` (1st position is a alphanumeric, 2nd and 3rd position can be space, next it can 8 to 13 alphanumeric)
3. `N0007120D  KAWE` (10 alphanumeric, 10th and 11th position can be space, next it can 1 to 4 alphanumeric)

I've tried:

1. ```
   (\b(?=[\dA-Za-z]*\d)(?=[\dA-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])[\dA-Za-z]{9,14}\b)
   ```
2. ```
   (\b[\dA-Z]{1}[\s]{1,2}[\dA-Z]{8,13}\b)
   ```
3. ```
   ((?=[\dA-Za-z]*\d)(?=[\dA-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])[\dA-Z]{10}[\s]{1,2}[\dA-Z]{1,4})
   ```

How can we create a single regex for all patterns

Comment: Why not just `or` your 3 expressions with `|`?

Comment: Is there a reason you only accept white space in certain positions? Does it have significance? Why not remove all white space and check `/^[a-z0-9]{9,14}$/i` ? Are you trying to validate input or extracting patters from a larger text? Please provide more context about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: What about characters from 1st to 8th? Can they be any or letters or digits or alphanumeric?

Comment: Note that your third example would have its first word match with the first rule. So how would you decide that the extra spacing and 4 letters would also need to be included?

Comment: Try `^(?:[\dA-Za-z]{9,14}|[\dA-Za-z] {1,2}[\dA-Za-z]{8,13}|[\dA-Za-z]{9} {1,2}[\dA-Za-z]{1,4})$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT53lS/1).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements alone above, the following worked for me:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,14}$|^[a-zA-Z0-9] {1,2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,13}$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10} {1,2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}$
```

Here is the explanation:

> ^: Match the beginning of the string
>
> $: Match the end of the string
>
> [a-zA-Z0-9]{9,14}: Match any alphanumeric characters between 9 and 14 times, inclusive (NOTE: [a-zA-Z] only matches characters, and \w also matches _)
>
> `space`{1,2}: Match 1 or 2 space characters

NOTE: Definitely check out [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: This would match a string with *two* space gaps also. Not sure if the OP wants that to happen...

Comment: Note that `\w` also matches `_`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work :

> /\^w{9,14}$|^\w\s{0,2}\w{8,13}$|^\w{9}\s{0,2}\w{1,4}$/